# Prevent subsequent systemd units to start

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd unit A (type=oneshot) that under some conditions triggers a system reboot.

I also have other systemd units B and C (type=simple) that already have an "After=A.service" condition that lets them start after A completes.

When A triggers a reboot I do not want B and C to start. What I observe with my setup is that B and C start when A completes and than immediately terminate due to the reboot.

I have already tried to make A create a temporary file (/tmp/foo) before triggering the reboot and to put a ConditionPathExists=!/tmp/foo condition in B and C, but this solution does not seem to work, B and C starts even though the file gets created.

How can I obtain this behavior?

Comment: is "rebooting" a normal mode of operation for A, or is it kind of a "A couldn't *really* start" condition? Because if it's the latter, you can just let A fail, and make B and C thus never get started, as their dependency never got started.

Comment: yes it is a normal mode of operation of A

Comment: But tmpfs isn't persistent storage, have you try to put your flag file to somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more of a hack than a real solution, you can try to just put a sleep after the reboot into A:

```
sleep 60
```

If the service continues running while the system is rebooting, the others shouldn't start, and a gets stopped by the reboot.

Not sure if that delays the shutdown though, but I guess you can find a good amount of time to sleep.